# UIPopoverPresentation and UIPopover dismissing causes crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, uipopover, zombie-process

I have been working on app for months without any popover issues.  All of a sudden today popovers have gone to hell.

I have tried this a few different ways and no matter when I dismiss the popover by pressing a button in the popover OR tapping outside of the popover the app crashes.

Using Instruments, I can see there is a zombie reference that only happens after the popover has been dismissed:

```
*** -[UITransitionView willRemoveSubview:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7f9985bcd980
```

So I have logged that stack and there isn't much help as the whole stack has to do with UIKit and built in animations, etc.

Using standard UIPopovers

```
self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.navVC];
self.popover.backgroundColor = [UIColor accentColor];
self.popover.delegate =self;
[self.seatingChartPopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(x,y, 1, 1)
                                          inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Or use the new UIPopoverPresentationController method in ios8

```
self.navVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;

UIPopoverPresentationController* popover = self.navVC.popoverPresentationController;
self.navVC.preferredContentSize = [self.childVC preferredContentSize];
popover.sourceView = self.view;
popover.sourceRect = CGRectMake(x,y, 1, 1);
popover.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
[self presentViewController:self.seatingChartNavController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I have made sure that all of the view controllers involved have a strong reference.

As I mentioned, I have not changed the the code that presents this popover in months and it's been working fine until today. I have spent hours debugging this to no avail.

Also, If I just present self.navVC as a normal modal view, the view displays fine and dismisses fine.  It's only when it's set as a popover that it fails

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm ashamed to admit that I accidentally put a dealloc method in one of my UIView Categories.

I am surprised this didn't bring up any sort of compiler warning, but after removing that there hasn't been any more bizarre crashing.